# How to show that $A \cup B = B \implies A \subset B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that

$$A \cup B = B \implies A \subset B$$

but I get stuck on:

$$x \in A \cup B = B$$
$$x \in B$$

Comment: Try the contrapositive: What if there was some element in $A \setminus B$?

Comment: To deduce the containment $A\subset B$, show that if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
A \subset A \cup B
$

$
A \cup B = B 
$

$
\implies A \subset B
$

Answer (score 4):

$$x\in A\cup B\Rightarrow x\in A \vee x\in B$$
Since $A\cup B=B$, if $x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B$. Therefore $A\subset B$.

Answer (score 3):

We have
\begin{align}
&x \in A \\
\Rightarrow \;&x \in A \cup B, \quad \text{since } A \subset A \cup B \\
\Rightarrow \;&x \in B, \quad \text{since } A \cup B = B \\
\end{align}
This shows that every element of $A$ is contained in $B$, which means that $A \subset B$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that if $A\cup B = B$, then $A\subset B$, so assume that $A\cup B = B$ (this is our hypothesis).

To prove that $A\subset B$, you must show that whenever $x\in A$, then also $x\in B$, so take an element $x\in A$.

Since $A\subset A\cup B$, we must also have that $x\in A\cup B$, but $A\cup B = B$, so actually $x\in B$. This proves what we set out to show: If $x\in A$, then $x\in B$.